# Suspension of system results in unresponsive lockscreen

Tags: release-loki, greeter, suspend, security

As the title says, the system will randomly "lock me out" of my laptop if it goes to sleep by itself. The lockscreen won't allow me to click and input my password again, which forces me to do a full reboot every single time it happens, which is annoying since it uses around 2 minutes to boot.

It's an older Packard Bell (Intel); a well supported device with no driver issues.